# NFC library for M24SR64

Tags: library, nfc

Im currently working on a project where i build an NFC device and needed some guidance in regards to the library needed for the NFC chip to work on the Arduino IDE. The chip is an M24SR64 chip and i've looked online for the library related to the chip but i couldn't find it. Although i did found a library for the M24SR64-y chip, though i'm not sure if its possible to use it, or whether it will work. If anyone has an idea or any help it would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Here you will find a lib for all [M24SR NFC tags](https://github.com/rena2019/ArduinoM24SR)

In this [test sketch](https://github.com/rena2019/ArduinoM24SR/blob/master/examples/NfcTagDisplay/NfcTagDisplay.ino) you find details how to connect and test the tag with Arduino.
 If it helps mark as accepted to help others.